# Why are my chrome extensions are not showing inside omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Recently I saw my all extension are pushed in small drop down menu on the right of chrome omnibox ? (see the screenshot)

[image]

This is a problem because now I have to make 2 clicks (first on drop down menu and second on extension) to use my pocket, or Alexa extension. Is there a workaround to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue you simply need to **expand your extensions tray** in Chrome. Using your mouse, *hover over the separator between the Omnibox and the » symbol, then click and drag to the left until you are satisfied.* voila!

[image: Drag Left to Expand Extensions Tray!]

Comment: Thanks, I have never guess it was so simple.  Now I feel like a idiot. lol